# Mysql update query to update a column in many rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns a and b. Something like :

```
     a  |  b
   +----+----+
     x  |  l
     y  |  m
     z  |  n
```

Using a single mysql update query, I want to update a column in many rows ...

```
update tableName set b = l1,m1,n1 where a= x,y,z respectively.
```

what should the update query for this be like?

Editing my question to make it more clear :
I dont want to append a 1 in the column values. I want to update them to new values which are not like the old ones. 
So is there any way to do that using **a single MYSQL query**?

Basically, I want to combine these queries into one :

```
update tableName set b=newVal, where a=something;
update tableName set b=anotherNewVal, where a=something_else;
update tableName set b=yetAnotherNewVal, where a=something_else_again;
```

Thanks much !

Comment: `update tableName set b = concat(b, '1') where a in ( 'x','y','z')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all your help. @Giorgos Betsos , @mynawaz and @Mathew. I found the query !

```
update tableName 
set b = case 
     when a ='x' then 'a is x' 
     when a ='y' then 'a is y' 
     else b 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE tableName SET b = CONCAT(b, '1') WHERE a = 'x' OR a = 'y' OR a = 'z'
```

OR

```
UPDATE tableName SET b = CONCAT(b, '1') WHERE a IN ('x', 'y', 'z')
```

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos Do you mind explaining CONCAT(b, '1')? What will it do? Will it set the value in column b to 1?

Comment: @Ridhima, `CONCAT(b, '1')` will concatenate the value of column `b` with `1` i.e. if the column `b` has value `m`, it will return `m1`, if the column `b` has value `n` it will return `n1` and so on. And `SET b = CONCAT(b, '1')` will concatenate the value of column `b` with `1` and set it to column `b`

Comment: oh okay.. actually that isnt what I am looking for. I probably should have made the question clearer.  What I want is to not append 1. m and m1 are totally different.  I want to update entirely different values in the columns using one query. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Ridhima, you should use `CASE` or `IF` then. `CASE` is better suited to your requirement as done by Mathew in his answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE `tableName`
 SET `tableName`.`b`= 
 CASE 
 WHEN `tableName`.`b`='l'  THEN 'l1'
 WHEN `tableName`.`b`='m'  THEN 'm1'
 WHEN `tableName`.`b`='n'  THEN 'n1'
 END
 WHERE `tableName`.`a`  IN ('x','y','z');
```

Comment: can you suggest me a better way.. so that I can use it if two rows have same value at column a?

Comment: I tried this query : `update tableName set b = (case when a='x' then 'a is x' when a='y' then 'a is y' end );`   It made this update, but also made all other values in column b to NULL. Can you please help me ?

Comment: `update tableName set b = (case a when 'x' then 'a is x' when 'y' then 'a is y' end);` query also does the same. Sets all other values to null.